# Need help with analysis proof

Tags: real-analysis

Given $\epsilon , \delta$ For a subset A in $\mathbb R^d$ And $diam(A)<\delta$ Then $diam(F(A))<\epsilon \implies $ sequences $\{x_n\},\{y_n\}$ in $\mathbb R^d$ Such that $||x_n-y_n|| \rightarrow 0$ Then $||F(x_n)-F(y_n)|| \rightarrow 0$

My attempt:
I need help showing this formally..  It seems to me that if the sup uniformly converges then all points of distance less than the sup would also converge.  Can the sequences be shown to be converging to points which are smaller than the sup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta >0$ with the property you stated in your question. Since $||x_n-y_n|| \to 0$, you have eventually $||x_n-y_n|| < \delta$.

Note that $diam \{ a,b\} $ is another way of writing $ ||a-b||$ whenever $a,b$ are two points. Hence

$$diam \{ x_n,y_n\} < \delta \Rightarrow ||F(x_n) -F(y_n)|| = diam \{ F(x_n) ,F(y_n)\} < \varepsilon$$

So $||F(x_n) -F(y_n)|| \to 0$.